# how to create procedure in mysql for selecting record?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how to write procedure in mysql to select record from particular table with IN and OUT parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delimiter //

create procedure sample (in id int, out MyCount int)
begin
    select count(*) into MyCount 
        from YourTable 
        where YourKey = id;
end//
```